# how to remove duplicate of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I have the below code, which on click of Add button duplicates DIV and its whole content. I want to ask how could I achieve getting new 'remove' button in a duplicated `div` in case it was added by accident and it would also remove whole duplicated `div`.

Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Submit Case Study</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var newNum = 1;
                cloneMe = function(el) {
                    var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'author' + newNum);
                    newElem.children().each(function(index, elem) {
                        $(elem).attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name', $(elem).attr('name') + newNum);
                    });
                    $('#authorlist').append(newElem);
                    newNum++;
                };
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .author {
                position: relative;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin: 1%;
                width: 96%;
                height: 80px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
            .boxtitle {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin: 3px;
                height: 50px;
                width: 6%;
            }
            .submit {
                position: relative;
                left: 47%;
                bottom: 30%;
            }
            .help-block {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #AAA;
                min-width: 75%;
                max-width: 75%;
                padding: 5px;
                margin-top: 1px;
                margin-left: 1%;
                /*border: 1px solid green;*/
            }
            .checkbox {
                position: relative;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 2em;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 1%;
            }
            .author {
                position: relative;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin: 1%;
                width: 96%;
                height: 80px;
            }
            .box {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin: 3px;
                height: 50px;
                min-width: 20%;
                max-width: 20%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .nameauthor {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 1%;
                width: 97%;
                background: #EEEEEE;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-style: inset;
                border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
            }
            .checboxauthor {
                position: relative;
                padding-top: 11px;
                float: left;
                width: 2%;
                height: 60px;
            }
            .boxbutton {
                position: relative;
                padding-top: 7px;
                margin-left: 3%;
                float: left;
                width: 8%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .button {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .boxtitle {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin: 3px;
                height: 50px;
                width: 6%;
            }
            .titleauthor {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 3.67%;
                width: 88%;
                background: #EEEEEE;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-style: inset;
                border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="submit" action="submit.php" method="GET">
            <div id="authorlist">
                <div class="author" id="author" name="author">
                    <div class="boxtitle" id="boxtitle" name="boxtitle">
                        <input type="text" class="titleauthor" id="title" name="title">
                        <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Title</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
                        <input type="text" class="nameauthor" id="f_name" name="f_name">
                        <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">First name</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
                        <input type="text" class="nameauthor" id="l_name" name="l_name">
                        <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Last name</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
                        <input type="text" class="nameauthor" id="email" name="email">
                        <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">E-mail address</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checboxauthor" id="checkboxauthor" name="checboxauthor">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
                        <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Contact</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxbutton" id="boxbutton" name="boxbutton">
                        <button type="button" class="button" id="AuthorButton" onclick="cloneMe($('#author'))" />Add author</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not checking duplicates before adding?

Comment: it is only in case of accidental click on add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add an event handler that will remove the div:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-btn", function() {
    $(this).closest(".author").remove();
});
```

After that, append the remove button when you clone the div:

```
newElem.append("<button class='remove-btn'>Remove</button>");
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add event handler? Thank you

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but it does not seem to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sjfcufne this should work only to duplicate main div, and I want ot achieve adding button to remove accidentaly added div

Comment: I can see that it is working however when I use it within my code it doesn't seems to do anything. any other idea?

Comment: Compare my fiddle and your code and check what is the difference.

Comment: it is identical to yours. all commas, semicolons everything is same as fiddle

Comment: I did get it sorted. I have referenced latest jQuery library and it worked.